# How to draw a "U" shapped graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a "U-Shape" graph with ggplot, but i didn't get a nicer result with this code:

```
df <- data.frame(y = seq(0,8,1),
                 x = c(10,8,7,3,1,3,7,8,10))

ggplot(df, aes(y = y)) +
   geom_line(aes(x = x))
```

can someone give me a help?

Comment: Maybe a "c-shaped graph?"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
x = seq(-10,10,1)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = x^2)

ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x)) +
geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `geom_path` is what you're looking for here, rather than `geom_line`. `geom_path` connects the values in the order they're in the data frame, while `geom_line` in the order along the x-axis.

```r
df <- data.frame(y = seq(0,8,1),
                 x = c(10,8,7,3,1,3,7,8,10))

ggplot(df, aes(y = y)) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x))
```

[image: U-shaped plot]

Comment: exactly! this is the answer. ty!

Comment: Feel free to hit that check mark if it solved your problem so others know you're happy with it and don't need more help!

Comment: i need to wait some minutes :P

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution.

```r
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(x) 1 + x^2
x <- seq(-10, 10)
y <- f(x)

ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]